# CSS Navigation Menu highlight selected menu item

Tags: html, css

I have developed an CSS navigation menu and for each navigation item I have written php.file.

**homepage.php**

[image]

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>My First Try Of CSS Navigation Bar</title>
  <style>
    /* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
    #nav {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 0 3em 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #nav li {
      float: left;
    }
    #nav li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #069;
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #nav li a:hover {
      color: #c00;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    /*
    End navigation bar styling. */
    /* This is just styling for this
    specific page. */
    body {
      background-color: #555;
      font: small/1.3 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    #wrap {
      width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      padding: 1em 8px;
      color: #333;
      background-color: #069;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #content {
      padding: 0 50px 50px;
    }
    .active {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <h1>Shree Shree Property, Kolhapur</h1> 
    <!-- Here's all it takes to make this navigation bar. -->
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="riteshproject/home.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About US</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact
    US</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- That's it! -->
    <div id="content">Area
      <tr>
        <td height="20px" />

        <td style="text-align:left">

          <select name="leavetype" id="leavetype">
            <?php $query="select code,areaname from areamaster" ; $query_run=mysql_query($query); mysql_num_rows($query_run); while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['code']?>">
              <?php echo $row[ 'areaname']?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**aboutus.php**

[image]

```
    <?php include( "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/riteshproject/config.php"); ?>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shree Shree Property,Kolhapur</title>
  <style>
    /* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
    #nav {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 0 5em 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    ul.primary li:hover a {
      background: pink;
      color: #666;
      text-shadow: none;
    }
    #nav li {
      float: left;
      background: #0080ff;
    }
    #nav li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 8px 17.5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: black;
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #nav li a:hover {
      color: black;
      background-color: #00bfff;
    }
    /* End navigation bar styling. */
    /* This is just styling for this specific page.
    */
    body {
      background-color: #555;
      font: small/1.3 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    #wrap {
      width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #00bfff;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      padding: 1em 8px;
      color: #333;
      background-color: #069;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #content {
      padding: 0 50px 50px;
    }
    h4 {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      float: center;
      padding: 1em 8px;
      color: #333;
      background-color: #00bfff;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-align-content: center;
      align-content: center;
    }
    #content {
      padding: 1em 8px;
    }
    #current a {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
    #dddd {
      color: red;
    }
    .active {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form name="tstest" action="test20.php" onsubmit="return CommonFunction(this);   method=" POST ">    <h1>Shree
    Shree Property, Kolhapur</h1>
             <!-- Here's all it takes to make this navigation bar. -->   <ul id="nav ">
            <li><a href="../riteshproject/home.php " class="active ">Home</a></li>      <li class="current " id="dddd "><a
    href="../riteshproject/aboutus.php ">About US</a></li>      <li><a
    href="# ">Contact US</a></li>
            <li><a href="# ">Login</a></li>         <li><a href="# ">Add Property</a></li>      <li><a href="# ">Luxarious Property</a></li>
            <li><a href="# ">Property For Sale</a></li>         <li><a href="# ">Other
    Services</a></li>    </ul>   <!-- That's it! -->  <div>    <html> 
    <body>     <div id="wrap ">

      <h4>Shree Shree Property<h4>   <p>Shree Shree Property provides
    leading property consultancy in Kolhapur</p>   </div>

     <body>  </html>     </form> </table> </div> </div>

    </body> </html>
```

i need to set color of only home menu that is first from left manu. then
i need to change color of only selected menu background
and whenver i navigate to another menu that menu color also need to change
and previously changed menu's color need as like i at home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done like this already. In home.php you use

```
<a href="../riteshproject/home.php" class="active">
```

So if you want to add same style to other pages just add this to your current php window.

```
class="active"
```

For example if you are on about.php Then open the file and change it to look like this. Also make sure that other a href tags do not have the same active class.

```
<a href="../riteshproject/aboutus.php" class="active">About US</a>
```

If you want to style it better just find or create active class in your css file

```
.active {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: i changed my home.php file to add class="active" but when i click on about us its not changing color of menu

Comment: you have to do the same in your about us page. Add active class where the <a href="#"> About us </a> is. 
<a href="../riteshproject/aboutus.php " class="Active">About US</a>

Comment: i also change my about us.php but color of menu not changing

Comment: Does it work with home.php ? This is really simple, maybe something is wrong with the styling side. Try not to use styles inside html tags, a lot easier to have them on the css.

Comment: i am very new to css can you plz tell me how and where i can add .active {
background-color: red;
}

Comment: Add it between <style> tags. But for future reference google on how to add css to your webpage.

Comment: ya its working fine really thanks  great work you are doing really appreciable

Comment: No problem. Also I would recommend reading this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp . When you start using css your php file structure will be better and it's a lot easier to style everything this way

Comment: thanks for your recommendation . i am strong in mysql 5.6 .just starting to design simple site using php/css/html .need much help from you in future .hope you will

Comment: haha If I see your post ofc. But there are a lot of friendly people who will help you out don't worry. Also check my answer as it was correct so other people wouldn't have to post similar ideas or it will help for beginners to find an answer for this problem. Good luck learning the front-end :)